# Custom COM class factory for managed in-proc server

Tags: c#, .net, com, com-interop, class-factory

I'm looking at implementing custom COM activation logic for a managed class library, in  `MkParseDisplayName/BindToObject` [manner](http://www.microsoft.com/library/images/msdn/library/periodic/periodic/msj/axcom797.htm).

This way, creating an object from VB might look like this:

```
obj = GetObject("clsid:12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234:!UniqueObjectId")
```

That would not be a problem for an out-of-proc server (using `CoRegisterClassObject`). However, for an in-proc server, I'd need to alter the implementation of `DllGetClassObject`, which is normally provided by `mscoree.dll`. **Is this possible at all?**

The only other option I see is to create a [C# singleton object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) to serve as class factory and implement [IParseDisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it. In theory, such singleton could also register a custom `IClassFactory` class object with `CoRegisterClassObject(CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)`, but the singleton itself would need to get instantiated first, anyway.

Comment: Do you want to be able to create different objects given a specific string, or just pass arguments to a newly created object? In the latter case, you can just declare & implement IParseDisplayName on the .NET class that's behind the 12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234 guid.

Comment: @SimonMourier, the original COM DLL (which is a candidate for rewrite in C#) has a class factory that implements `IParseDisplayName` (exactly as described [here](http://www.microsoft.com/library/images/msdn/library/periodic/periodic/msj/axcom797.htm)), and then creates different objects, depending on the trailing item of the moniker. Ideally, I'd like to keep that behavior.

Comment: You could mangle the default .NET registry setup to point to a specific DLL, not mscoree

Comment: I thought about it, but i don't know how to export `DllGetClassObject` from a managed C# DLL, not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but kinda hacky (but you're in hack world already :-): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818850/is-is-possible-to-export-functions-from-a-c-sharp-dll-like-in-vs-c

Comment: ildasm is an interesting, albeit a bit too extreme option, thanks :-)